# How to show Wordpress Dashboard Widgets on Frontend?

Tags: widgets, front-end, dashboard

I want to use Wordpress Dashboard Widgets as it is easy to add new widgets and automatically have the functionality of drag and drop, changing the order, showing and hiding widgets and also importantly setting custom roles and only showing certain widgets to certain users. I however want this functionality to appear on the frontend of the website under a logged in users profile page. I'm currently using the Ultimate member plugin for the user profiles.

Any suggestions on how to do this or alternatives for doing this would be appreciated. I also considered just changing the styling of the dashboard to such an extent that it looks like the frontend, but this might not be the ideal solution.

Comment: What have you coded so far? Please post your work which includes your attempt to code a solution.

Comment: I haven't coded much, I just used the plugin Adminimize to hide all the dashboard menus and played around with the styling to make the dashboard look more like the frontend, but this is not the ideal solution. Or maybe it is the best solution after all?

Answer (score -1):

After trying to build dashboard functionality on the "frontend" of a site, the WPMU multi-site alternative was to seriously minimize, strip-down, and customize a template for the user type that required that functionality.  They login directly to the dashboard, or can be linked their from their account page when logging in.  Everything you described is controllable as a user site dashboard under a multi-site build.

Assuming you don;t mind users having their own "sites" - this could be a better approach to offer the functionality.